# Facebook event checkin - is it supported in the graph API?

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, checkin

Does anyone know if the new FB events checkin feature which is available on the mobile phone is supported in the graph API?

I couldn't find any information about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to checkin to an event using the Graph API.

Regards

Jonathan.